# Recover master key from active LUKS partition

Tags: linux, disk-encryption, luks

I have an open LUKS partition (open meaning that it is decrypted and mounted) the passphrase to which I would like to recover. It used to be possible to just add a new key slot by recovering the master key and using this to set the new slot as described [in section 6.10 of the FAQ here](https://gitlab.com/cryptsetup/cryptsetup/-/wikis/FrequentlyAskedQuestions). However, this does not work for the device in question. The command

```
dmsetup table --target crypt --showkey /dev/mapper/<device>
```

is, according to the FAQ, supposed to print something like (this is not my key, this is copied from the FAQ):

```
0 200704 crypt aes-cbc-essiv:sha256 a1704d9715f73a1bb4db581dcacadaf405e700d591e93e2eaade13ba653d0d09 0 7:0 4096
```

where the `a1704d9715f73a1bb4db581dcacadaf405e700d591e93e2eaade13ba653d0d09` bit is the key. Instead, I now get

```
[...] :64:logon:cryptsetup:<device UUID> [...]
```

in this position. For this device, which is an external USB drive. For internal disks, it works as expected.

The device UUID it prints is the same as the one you get in the UUID line when calling

```
sudo cryptsetup luksDump /dev/<USB device>
```

This seems to be the case for all encrypted external disks (as opposed to internal drives, for which it works as expected). I do not understand why there should be this kind of difference between internal and external disks. As far as I can tell the encryption is the same (twofish-xts-essiv:sha256), cryptsetup version is 2.0.2. Kernel is 4.15.0.

EDIT: I notice that it may have something to do with [this](https://gitlab.com/cryptsetup/cryptsetup/-/issues/453), that somehow there was a version change from LUKS1 to LUKS2 with keys not being accessible from userspace any longer in LUKS2. I still do not understand, however, why there would be this difference between internal and external disks; I used the same LUKS version to decrypt/open them.

Comment: There's a flag `--disable-keyring` in the `cryptsetup` CLI (and a corresponding flag in libcryptsetup) which deactivates the LUKS2 feature: By default in LUKS2, the volume key is apparently put into a kernel space where it's impossible to extract from user space. With LUKS1 or the `--disable-keyring` flag, it's put into dmcrypt.